# How to extract all email address from text in swift

Tags: regex, swift

I have a text

var txt = "+abc@gmail.com heyyyyy cool +def@gmail.com"

I want to extract the email address from the text and store it in an array. I want to do it with regular expression. I found the regular expression, but i am not able to save the email in to an array.

i tried

```
let regEx = "/(\\+[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi"
if let email = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", regEx) {
        //what to do here
}
```

Or am i doing wrong?
I know this is a basic question. Please help

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

These code worked for me. You can checkout email regex from [here](http://emailregex.com/).

**SWIFT 5**

```
func extractEmailAddrIn(text: String) -> [String] {
    var results = [String]()

    let emailRegex = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
    let nsText = text as NSString
    do {
        let regExp = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: emailRegex, options: .caseInsensitive)
        let range = NSMakeRange(0, text.count)
        let matches = regExp.matches(in: text, options: .reportProgress, range: range)

        for match in matches {
            let matchRange = match.range
            results.append(nsText.substring(with: matchRange))
        }
    } catch (let error) {
        print(error)
    }

    return results
}
```

**SWIFT 3**

```
func extractEmailAddrIn(text: String) -> [String] {
    var results = [String]()
    
    let emailRegex = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
    let nsText = text as NSString
    do {
        let regExp = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: emailRegex, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive)
        let range = NSMakeRange(0, text.characters.count)
        let matches = regExp.matchesInString(text, options: .ReportProgress, range: range)
        
        for match in matches {
            let matchRange = match.range
            results.append(nsText.substringWithRange(matchRange))
        }
        
    } catch _ { 
    }
    
    return results
}
```

Comment: The regex is almost identical to the one in the link mentioned (http://emailregex.com). I think it maybe a copy/paste error: `[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}` the one in the answer is missing the last 4

Comment: If you have a text with emoticons like " a@b.com" then this extraction won't detect a@b.com as email address because `text.count` equals 9 but `matchesInString` needs a bigger range of 12. Change `text.count` to `text.utf16.count` and it works

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using the `NSRegularExpression` class instead of `NSPredicate`.  The format for the regular expressions is from the [ICU](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp).

Here is one way to do it:

```
let pattern = "(\\+[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)"
let regexp = NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive, error: nil)

let str = "+abc@gmail.com heyyyyy cool +def@gmail.com" as NSString

var results = [String]()
regexp?.enumerateMatchesInString(str, options: NSMatchingOptions(0), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: str.length), usingBlock: { (result: NSTextCheckingResult!, _, _) in
    results.append(str.substringWithRange(result.range))
})

// Gives [+abc@gmail.com, +def@gmail.com]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your regex name is wrong. You declare it as `regEx` but in your `NSPredicate` you use `emailRegEx`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the plus sign in the mail address?

**Without + sign in the address:**

`([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)`

Result: ["abc@gmail.com", "def@gmail.com"]

**With + sign in the address:**

`([\\+a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)`

Result: ["+abc@gmail.com", "+def@gmail.com"]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the String extensions I have created to extract emails from It works well in swift 4.

```
 extension String {    
  func getEmails() -> [String] {
    if let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}", options: .caseInsensitive)
    {
        let string = self as NSString
        
        return regex.matches(in: self, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.length)).map {
            string.substring(with: $0.range).lowercased()
        }
    }
    return []
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
let test = "Precision Construction John Smith cONSTRUCTION WORKER 123 Main St, Ste. 30o 
www.precsioncontructien.com adil@gmail.com fraz@gmail.pk janesmit@precisiencenstruction.com 555.555.5SS5"
            let emails = test.getEmails()
 print(emails)
```

// results ["adil@gmail.com", "fraz@gmail.pk", "janesmit@precisiencenstruction.com"]

Comment: why the  `.replacingOccurrences(of: "", with: "")`